# yajra datatable fractal remove data key from included attributes

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-5.5, yajra-datatable, thephpleague-fractal

I want to use [laravel-datatables-fractal](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-fractal) for transforming server-side response using Fractal.

First I wrote a transformer for `Product` model like this :

```
class ProductTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    protected $availableIncludes = [
        'prices'
    ];

    public function transform(Product $product)
    {
        $transforms = [
            'product_id'     => $product->product_id,
            'code'           => $product->code,
            'title'          => $product->title,
            'description'    => $product->description,
        ];

        return $transforms;
    }

    public function includePrices(Product $product)
    {
        $prices = $product->prices;

        return $this->collection($prices, new PriceTransformer, FALSE);
    }
}
```

As you can see there is an included `prices` attribute that uses  another transformer named `PriceTransformer`.

And in the `ProductController` that makes and returns result of all products as a datatable formatted response I have a `datatable` method like this:

```
public function datatable(Request $request)
    {
        return app('datatables')->of(Product::all())
            ->setTransformer(new ProductTransformer)
//            ->setSerializer(new CustomArraySerializer())
            ->make(TRUE);
    }
```

Response is returned but a problem that I have is : when I want to return `prices` included attribute , it returned as a `data` attribute like this :

```
{
    "draw": 0,
    "recordsTotal": 8,
    "recordsFiltered": 8,
    "data": [
        {
            "product_id": 1,
            "title": "Product Title 1",
            "for_sale": true,
            "for_purchase": true,
            "changeable": false,
            "returnable": false,
            "sale_price": "40000.00",
            "purchase_price": "5000.00",
            "creator": 1,
            "created_at": "2017-12-11 12:21:49",
            "updated_at": "2017-12-14 11:55:52",
            "prices": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "sale_price": "30000.00",
                        "created_at": "2017-12-11 12:21:49"
                    },
                    {
                        "sale_price": "40000.00",
                        "created_at": "2017-12-11 12:39:00"
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "product_id": 11,
            "title": "Product Title 11",
            "for_sale": true,
            "for_purchase": true,
            "changeable": false,
            "returnable": false,
            "sale_price": "50000.00",
            "purchase_price": "40000.00",
            "creator": 1,
            "created_at": "2017-12-16 11:07:43",
            "updated_at": "2017-12-16 11:07:43",
            "prices": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "sale_price": "50000.00",
                        "created_at": "2017-12-16 11:07:43"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "input": {
        "include": "prices"
    }
}
```

I want to remove `data` from included attributes and they be in this format for example :

```
"prices": [
           {
            "sale_price": "50000.00",
            "created_at": "2017-12-16 11:07:43"
           }
          ]
```

Even I added a serializer (as you see in above code and is commented) with below content that I used it for all other responses and worked well :

```
class CustomArraySerializer extends ArraySerializer
{
    public function collection($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        if ($resourceKey === FALSE) {
            return $data;
        }

        return ['success' => TRUE, 'result' => $data];
    }

    public function item($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        if ($resourceKey === FALSE) {
            return $data;
        }

        return ['success' => TRUE, 'result' => $data];
    }
}
```

But when use it I got this error :

```
{
    "draw": 0,
    "recordsTotal": 8,
    "recordsFiltered": 0,
    "data": [],
    "error": "Exception Message:\n\nUndefined index: data"
}
```

What is problem and how can solve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Spatie/Transformer "[spatie/laravel-fractal](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal)", try using following after adding above mentioned package.

```
public function datatable(Request $request)
{
    return app('datatables')->of(Product::all())
    ->setTransformer(new ProductTransformer)
    ->serializeWith(new \Spatie\Fractalistic\ArraySerializer())
    ->make(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: I tried your package and used `serializeWith` as you suggest but this error occurred now : `Method serializeWith does not exist.`

Comment: Now I used this way and problem is solved : `$products = Product::all();
        $products = fractal()
            ->collection($products)
            ->transformWith(new ProductTransformer)
            ->serializeWith(new \Spatie\Fractalistic\ArraySerializer())
            ->toArray();

        return app('datatables')->of($products)
            ->make(TRUE);`

For that I marked your solution as answer.